# how to render two rasters as one image with gradient colors in r?

Tags: r, colors, plot, raster

everyone,

I have two rasters with same range from -1 to 1 and same extent.

What I want to do is drawing an image combined with these two rasters, and the colors of the cell can uniquely express what value it should be in two rasters respectively.

e.g. r1 is one of rasters, r2 is another, when r1=0 & r2=0, the color is white, both of r1 and r2 is positive, the color is series of green, both is negetive, the color is series of purple, r1>0 and r2<0, the color is series of orange, r1<0 and r2>0, the color is series of blue (I guess). Of course, the color should be gradient with the values.

In addition, there still should be a legend to express how the color corresponded to the value, the legend is a rectangle, its center is white corresponding to 0 in axes X and 0 in axes Y.

I am new in stackoverflow, so I don't have enough reputations to upload example map to express exactly.

I am in hurry to draw this map. I hope you are interesting to my question.
As soon I can quote image, I will upload the example to show what I want.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I think you can *link* to an image uploaded elsewhere even with low points. You can also give us some sample code to generate example (small) rasters for demo purposes.

Comment: If r1>0 and r2>0 then you say colour is a series of green, but what controls the shade of green? The value of r1, r2, or r1+r2?